# How to properly use RobustScaler for improving LinearRegression model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, robust, standardization

As to improve my LinearRegression model I was adviced to use Standardization, i.e. RobustScaler for better performance.
My shapes of train and validation sets:

```
Train set: (4304, 20) (4304,)
Validation set: (1435, 20) (1435,)
```

So I transform my X for both train and validation sets:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

scaler = RobustScaler()
X_train_robust_scaler = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.copy())
X_valid_robust_scaler = scaler.transform(X_valid.copy())
```

Then I run the model and print scores with function print_score():

```
from sklearn import linear_model

regr_vol_2 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr_vol_2.fit(X_train_robust_scaler, y_train)

def print_score(m, X_train: pd.DataFrame, X_valid: pd.DataFrame, y_train: pd.Series, y_valid:pd.Series):
'''Function takes a model and calculates and prints its RMSE values and r² 
scores for train and validation set. Also attaches oob_score for Random 
Forest model.
Parameters:
-----------
(1) m --> given model;
(2) X_train --> training set of independent features;
(3) X_valid --> validation set of independent features;
(4) y_train --> training set of dependent features;
(5) y_valid --> validation set of dependent features;
-----------
Returns scoring values in the following order: 
[training rmse, validation rmse, r² for training set, r² for validation set, 
oob_score_]
'''
res = [rmse(m.predict(X_train), y_train),
       rmse(m.predict(X_valid), y_valid),
       m.score(X_train, y_train), m.score(X_valid, y_valid)]
if hasattr(m, 'oob_score_'): res.append(m.oob_score_)
return print(res)


print_score(regr_vol_2,X_train_robust_scaler, X_valid_robust_scaler,y_train, y_valid)
```

| Output | [training rmse, validation rmse, r² for training set, r² for validation set |
| --- | --- |
| before: | [260.86301672800016, 271.8005003802866, 0.6184501389479591, 0.5976532655109332] |
| after: | [260.8630167262612, 271.800437195055, 0.6184501389530468, 0.5976534525773189] |

Both quite same result, what I did wrong ? I should you *Robustscaler()* also for **y_train** and **y_valid** ?
If I do it:

```
scaler_y = RobustScaler()
y_train_robust_scaler = scaler_y.fit_transform(y_train[:,None])
y_valid_robust_scaler = scaler_y.transform(y_valid[:,None])
```

I got the same as without it:
| [training rmse, validation rmse, r² for training set, r² for validation set |
| -------------- |
| [260.8630167262612, 271.800437195055, 0.6184501389530468, 0.5976534525773189]|

Or I should use *Robustscaler()* on whole data at one time before split ? If 'Yes',  how can I do it if I impute NaN values after  splitting in train/validation.

Answer (score 0):

**Scaling does not affect an unpenalized regression.**  It can improve convergence of the solver, but if the model is converging satisfactorily on the raw data, the results will be the same.

Comment: Can you advice what I need to do in order to raise r-squared metric ?

Comment: That's too broad a question for the stackexchange format (and off-topic at StackOverflow; see stats.SE or datascience.SE).  But a couple of suggestions: try regularized regression (lasso, ridge, or elasticnet; in these cases, definitely scale first; however, your training R2 is not much higher than the validation, so I wouldn't count on much improvement), or try a nonlinear model (either by adding nonlinear terms, or using a natively nonlinear regression model).